# Getting null values for accessing data in doctrine repository

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I get null values for User entity connected through id with Friends entity when getting the data from FriendsRepo

I have tried accessing the data from UsersRepo too without success.

User entity:

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
 */
private $email;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_picture", type="string", nullable=true)
 *
 */
private $userPic;

/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\UserPosts", mappedBy="user")
 *
 *
 */

private $userPosts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->userPosts = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->myfriends = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->friendof = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Friends", mappedBy="afriendof")
 */

private $friendof;
/**
 * @var
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Friends", mappedBy="friendsWithMe")
 */
private $myfriends;
 /**
 * @return User
 */
public function getFriendof()
{
    return $this->friendof;
}

/**
 * @param User $friendof
 */
public function setFriendof($friendof)
{
    $this->friendof = $friendof;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getMyfriends()
{
    return $this->myfriends;
}

/**
 * @param User $myfriends
 */
public function setMyfriends($myfriends)
{
    $this->myfriends = $myfriends;
}
}
```

Friends entity:

```
class Friends
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="myfriends")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */

private $friendsWithMe;


/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="friendof")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="friend_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */

private $afriendof;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="smallint")
 */
private $status;



/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getFriendsWithMe()
{
    return $this->friendsWithMe;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $friendsWithMe
 */
public function setFriendsWithMe($friendsWithMe)
{
    $this->friendsWithMe = $friendsWithMe;
}

/**
 * @return User
 */
public function getAfriendof()
{
    return $this->afriendof;
}

/**
 * @param mixed $afriendof
 */
public function setAfriendof($afriendof)
{
    $this->afriendof = $afriendof;
}

/**
 * @return integer
 */
public function getStatus()
{
    return $this->status;
}

/**
 * @param integer $status
 */
public function setStatus($status)
{
    $this->status = $status;
}
}
```

My FriendsRepo:

```
public function personalFriends($userId){
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $result = $em->createQuery('SELECT friends FROM AppBundle\Entity\Friends friends WHERE friends.friendsWithMe= :userId');
    $result->setParameter('userId', $userId);
    return $result->getResult();
}
```

I expect to get the data of the friend's username, picture, but I get null values on every piece of data except id, I know that the problem is something super small but I could not find solution to it, so please help(example):

```
DefaultController.php on line 38:
array:1 [▼
  0 => Friends {#649 ▼
-friendsWithMe: User {#436 ▼
  -id: 45
  -email: "pesho1@abv.bg"
  -username: "pesho"
  -password: "$2y$13$5TYROts3shJjgZ41CNUE8.bMTG.JNwKGdzRuKMVSlySULFEAttVyK"
  -userPic: "fb9afe572dce4a0f82481c42063b727f.jpeg"
  -userPosts: PersistentCollection {#564 ▶}
  -friendof: PersistentCollection {#412 ▶}
  -myfriends: PersistentCollection {#414 ▶}
  -roles: "ROLE_ADMIN"
  -isActive: null
}
-afriendof: User {#596 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 12
  -email: null
  -username: null
  -password: null
  -userPic: null
  -userPosts: null
  -friendof: null
  -myfriends: null
  -roles: null
  -isActive: null
   …2
}
-status: 0
}
]
```

Comment: It's seems to be a "lazy loading" problem `+__isInitialized__: false`. Can u send us the code where your called the repository and where you try to access "afrienfof" data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because of the lazy loading which is enabled by default. You need to explicitly join the user table.

```
$result = $em->createQuery('SELECT friends, user FROM AppBundle\Entity\Friends friends JOIN AppBundle\Entity\User user WHERE friends.friendsWithMe= :userId');
```

This way the data will be fetched immediately. Otherwise, the data would be fetched the first time you try to access it, i.e.

```
$friend->getAFriendOf()->getEmail();
```

Comment: Sorry for the dump question but after doing what you told me I get in my data array with all the users including the friends data. Is the `WHERE` clause the problem for loading all the users?? How can I correct the query in order to load only the two friends and not all other users too?